Every proper ideal with the Frèchet Property is meager.
I need to prove the above statement.
The definition of Frèchet Property is the following.
Let $\mathcal{I}$ be an ideal on a countably infinite set $X$ which contains every finite subset of $X$. We say that $\mathcal{I}$ has the Frèchet Property if for any $A \subseteq X$ with $A \notin \mathcal{I}$, there exists $B \subseteq A$ such that every infinite subset of $B$ is not in $\mathcal{I}$.
My Try:
Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a proper ideal on $X \times X$ with the Frèchet Property (FP). We define a function $F\colon 2^{X \times X} \to 2^{N \times N}$ by $F(A) = g[A]$ for any $A \subseteq 2^{X \times X}$, where $g$ is a 1-1 mapping from $X \times X$ onto $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Then $F$ is a homeomorphism which preserves ideals.
Let $\mathcal{I'} = \{A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \:\: A \cap(\{n \} \times \mathbb{N}) \text{ is finite}\}$.
I proved that $\mathcal{I'}$ is meager on $2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$. I would like to show that $\mathcal{I} \subseteq F^{-1}[\mathcal{I'}]$. This would imply that $\mathcal{I}$ is meager in $2^{X \times X}$. I think it is enough with that because $2^{X \times X}$ is homeomorphic to $2^X$. The problem is that I don't know how to prove that $\mathcal{I} \subseteq F^{-1}[\mathcal{I'}]$. I don't know even if this is possible.
Can anyone give me a suggestion please?
